# Surfing Internet & Reading Book is OK when there's nothing to do?

Tags: internship

It has been 1 week since I joined the work. But still no tasks are assigned. Should I inform to manager?

Comment: Absolutely. I do it even when there are things to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you have nothing to do:

- Inform your superior
- Acquaint yourself with the tools you will be using, be it CAD, IDE:s etc.
- Explore the "black hole", every company (I haven't been employed by a single one yet where this is not the case) has a file system that is difficult to navigate and where information is stored haphazardly. The problem is often trying to find the information you need rather than actually doing a certain task.
- Read up on company policies,
- Get to know your colleagues
- Be proactive

**Edit**
As it has been pointed out in the comments below, it is presumptious  to assume that someone is working in a code environment. Given the nature of many questions it is an easy mistake to make, the answer has been corrected to be more general.

Comment: "Acquaint yourself with the code base" is kind of presumptive. Though it can be hard to tell by looking at this site sometimes, there are plenty of jobs that don't involve code in any way.

Comment: It's also dangerous if OP works in an environment with code, but isn't responsible for it (QA, IT etc)